# Flutter build ListTiles from Firebase map of arrays

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter

The end game for my application is for users to be able to add, edit and remove "object classes" using Firebase.  I am not sure the best way to go about this, so what I am working on is based on the assumption that the best method is to use Arrays for the classes and to put these arrays under a Map, so that I can somehow reference a specific array later.    If this is not the best way to achieve this then I am happy to scrap it for something better, just let me know!

So the database, using the Map > Arrays design looks like so:

```
ObjectsList  >  CarsMap (Map)
 (document)      - sh899873jsa (Array)
                     0  "Toyota"
                     1  "Supra"
                     2  "1996"
                     3  "$4990"

                   - hasd823j399 (Array)
                     0  "Toyota"
                     1  "Corolla"
                     2  "2014"
                     3  "$11990"

                   - nelaoiwi283 (Array)
                     0  "Ford"
                     1  "Territory"
                     2  "2018"
                     3  "$35000"
```

So the first point I am stuck at is simply how to build ListTiles from this data.  I can't get the syntax right, because I don't know how to work with the map and can't find examples online.  This is what I have, first the build widget, which has a StreamBuilder:

```
Container(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('User').document('ObjectsList').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return LoadingAnimation();
        } else {
          return ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: _buildCarsList(snapshot),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
```

And then the _buildCarsList function, simplified:

```
_buildCarsList(AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  return snapshot.data.data.values
    .map((doc) => doc[0] == "Toyota" ? Container(
      child: Text(
        doc[1],
      ),
    ),
```

Seems to always return null, so I know I am writing this wrong but I have been trying different things for hours upon hours with no success.

If it helps, snapshot.data.data.values returns:

```
({sh899873jsa: [Toyota, Supra, 1996, $4990], hasd823j399: [Toyota, Corolla, 2014, $11990], nelaoiwi283: [Ford, Territory, 2018, $35000]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a object class.

```
class Car {
  final String make;
  final String model;
  final int year;
  final String price;

  Car({
     this.make,
     this.model,
     this.year,
     this.price
  });
}
```

Map your array to the object class, and then use a `ListView.builder` to build your list.

```
Container(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('User').document('ObjectsList').snapshots().map(_mapCars),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return LoadingAnimation();
        } else {
          List<Car> listOfCars = snapshot.data; //Maps data to your object as a list
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listOfCars.length,
            itemBuilder: (Build context, int index)
              ListTile(
                title: Text(listOfCars[index].make); //Toyota
              ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Map:

```
List<Car> _mapCars(Querysnapshot cars){
  return cars.documents.map((doc){
    return Car(
      make: doc.data['make'],
      model: doc.data['model'],
      year: doc.data['year'],
      price: doc.data['price],
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

**NOTE:** This is retrieved using the firestore package **BEFORE** version *0.14.0+2* - if you are using a version above *0.14.0+2* then use:

```
List<Car> _mapCars(Querysnapshot cars){
  return cars.docs.map((doc){
    return Car(
      make: doc.data()['make'],
      model: doc.data()['model'],
      year: doc.data()['year'],
      price: doc.data()['price],
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

Flutter works better when your declare the data you want to work with - usually with object models.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but your code gives the error:  A value of type DocumentSnapshot cannot be assigned to a variable of type List<Car>.    I can change your code to this:   List<Car> listOfCars = snapshot.data as List<Car>;   And then the app will run, but then at run-time you get:  type 'DocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List<Car>' in type cast.

Comment: Sorry about the delay - I have updated my answer to map the data :)